# Are There Any Good Open-Source Mac Application Templates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, templates

I am looking to make a Mac version of one of my iPhone apps and was looking for a good ay to hit the ground running.  I know how to code in Objective-c and Cocoa, and I know how to piece something together from scratch if I have to, but I am looking for an easier way.

Are there any open-source templates for coding Mac desktop applications that I might be able to pick up and use to get started off without reinventing the wheel?

### EDIT:

I guess what I am looking for is an easy way to get started on an app that has the "iTunes Look and Feel".  If there are some bare-bones version of this layout as some sort of template project, that would be great.  Also, why has somebody down-voted this question?  Have I asked something that is not appropriate for SO?

Comment: I suspect the down vote was because the question was not sufficiently well posed to get a reasonable answer. With your clarification, things may be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for a starting point for the interface, then check out BW Toolkit:

http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/

He has some nice videos on his site showing how to create a Mail-like interface very quickly.

Answer (score 6):

Apple includes lots of project templates with Xcode (vanilla application, document-based application, Core Data document-based application, etc.). I don't really know how much more you would want in a template. They're generally pretty good for getting you started, I think. If you're looking for something more than these offer out of a "template," maybe you could elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the project templates included with Xcode, you should browse the application exmples in `/Developer/Examples`. Most of these examples are "full" applications that demonstrate one or more Cocoa-related concepts. Many could serve as the starting point for a similarly orriented app of your own.